# Testing angular promises with jasmine returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have the following js code

```
foo() {
   return this.bar().then(response => { 
       return 'I am a cat'; 
     });
   }
```

I want to test the result of this function and have the following jasmine test:

```
spyOn(MyService, 'bar').and.returnValue($q.when('dummy response'))

MyService.foo().then(result => console.log(result));
$rootScope.$digest();
```

The code works correctly because it is working in the browser but the test prints 'undefined' instead of 'I am a cat' as I would expect. Does anyone know why or how I make it print 'I am a cat'?

Comment: fixed above typo (though there is no typo in real version of code)

Comment: The code looks ok. Maybe the $rootScope.$digest(); influences the OtherService reference. You can try to remove $rootScope.$digest();

Comment: It isn't clear what is going on in this test and this service. Please, provide all relevant code instead of truncated snippets. The fact that there is a  `MySerice` typo suggests that real code may differ from the one you've posted. The question lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There's no point in $rootScope.$digest() here, it should be usually performed after promise chain.

Comment: Ok it is after and is still undefined. Which part is unlcear to you @estus ?

Comment: What is the exact code of this test and this service. The question lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and can be closed as off-topic. If it's not clear to you why the problem happens, it isn't clear to anybody else.

Comment: It's not clear to me why the problem happens because I am a JVM engineer and know next to nothing about this ecosystem. I thought everything that I removed was boilerplate (though it's more than likely I am wrong) so when I ask 'what else is required' I mean literally 'what else is required'. I am not giving the exact code partly because the service is a couple of hundred lines long and irrelevant to the question and partly because it contains domain specific information which I can't post publicly.